# Get max value in column with specific text in "header"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sheet2

[image: 1]

So I'm good in vba, but not formulas. From **another sheet** I need to

1. find the column with "Power" in sheet 2 row 1
2. get the max value in that column

I can do each separately, but not together.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Something like `=MAX(XLOOKUP("Power",<Row1>,<OtherRows>))`

Comment: "can do each separately" <-- would u mind sharing the formula used?